# Spawning language server with cmd`diagnostic-languageserver`failed. The language server is either not installed, missing from PATH, or not executable

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvXgH.png)

" Spawning language server with cmd: `diagnostic-languageserver` failed. The language server is either not installed, missing from PATH, or not executable "

nvim problem
i copied devaslife's dotfiles and installed plugin
yesterday it work, but today i entered LSP info after that when i Enter shows that the error

Answer (score 4):

I've resolved this problem by executing the below command

```
npm install -g diagnostic-languageserver
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
yarn global add diagnostic-languageserver
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, it's because you have not set up the right programming language that you are using in the **lspconfig.rc.vim**, precisely in the ***nvim_lsp.tsserver.setup*** part.

I had the same problem because I was in javascript file (.js) and the lsp config that I was using from someone else only supports typescript files. So, I just had to add the `javascript`, `javascriptreact` and `javascript.jsx`. For example :

```
nvim_lsp.tsserver.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  filetypes = { "typescript", "typescriptreact", "typescript.tsx", "javascript", "javascriptreact", "javascript.jsx" },
  capabilities = capabilities
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For windows you can use this:

```
nvim_lsp.tsserver.setup {
    on_attach = on_attach,
    filetypes = { "typescript", "typescriptreact", "typescript.tsx" },
    cmd = { "typescript-language-server.cmd", "--stdio" }
}
```

This will make sure it will run the .cmd file that is along side the .ps1.

Answer (score 0):

That is not working for me. In the ***lspconfig.re.vim***, i had to delete the "javascipt", "javasriptreact", "javascript.jsx" types from the ***nvim_lsp.diagnosticls.setup/filetypes***, and then put them in the ***nvim_lsp.tsserver.setup>filetypes***

Answer (score 0):

On macOS:

```bash
brew install marksman
```